# why when i make belongsTo with "id" it works but with "category_id" it dont works laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

belongsTo dont work

Model Class:

```
class Product extends Model
{

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Category",'category_id');
    }

}
```

but belongsTo with "id" (not category_id) works and select categories with same id as product
and when I change it on "category_id" it dont works

database :

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("title");
            $table->string("description");
            $table->integer("price");
            $table->string("size");
            $table->bigInteger("type_id")->unsigned();
            $table->foreign("type_id")->references("id")->on("types");
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->integer("views")->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling relation `category()` in Products Controller?

Comment: I solved problem. Problem was that when I selected product from database I selected only "title" "price" and "id" columns so I added "category_id"  to select and it works

Comment: When you ask a question, you need to include all relevant information. You didn't post the code showing where/how you're using this relationship, and that was where you had the issue. Please be sure to include more information in the future. Glad you got this working though!